# Parse Divs to Create UL/LI List Removing Duplicates

Tags: jquery, list, parsing, html, duplicates

Need some jQuery advice...

I have in DOM divs with delimited entries like this:

```
<div class="my-data">collie; german shepherd;</div>
<div class="my-data">collie; cocker spaniel; pug; poodle;</div>
<div class="my-data">poodle; german shepherd;</div>
```

I need to convert this to an alphabetized list with duplicates removed:

```
<ul id="new-list">
<li>cocker spaniel</li>
<li>collie</li>
<li>german shepherd</li>
<li>poodle</li>
<li>pug</li>
</ul>
```

Trying to determine the fastest jQuery method to achieve this; I'll have about 500 divs on a page to convert when a page loads.

Comment: Since it is pure java script it wont take much time even if you have 2000 divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $myData = $('.my-data').detach(), list = [], listHtml = ['<ul><li>'];

$myData.each(function(i, el) {
    var txt = $(el).text().split(';');
    $.each(txt, function(idx, val) {
        var val = $.trim(val);
        if (val && val != '' && $.inArray(val, list) == -1) {
         list.push(val);
        }
    });
});

list.sort();
listHtml.push(list.join('</li><li>'));
listHtml.push('</li></ul>');

$('body').append(listHtml.join(''));
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/BWBsj/

Comment: Wow, this is a minimal amount of code to accomplish the correct  result. Pefect! This is so much better than my own cumbersome solution at http://jsfiddle.net/jbeacher/9qfpn/8/ that didn't sort right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var sorting = [];

 var divs = $('.my-data');
    $.each(divs,function(){ 
    var instr = $(this).html().split(';');
     for(i=0;i<instr.length;i++){
     if(instr[i] !=""){
      sorting.push(instr[i]);
      }
      };

    });

    sorting.sort();

    var str = '<ul id="new-list">';
     for(i=0;i<sorting.length;i++){
     if((sorting[i] != sorting[i+1]) && sorting[i+1] !="undefined"){
       str += '<li>'+sorting[i]+'</li>';
       }
    };
    str += '</ul>';
$('#container').html(str);
});
</script>

</head> 
<body>  

  <div class="my-data">collie; german shepherd;</div>
<div class="my-data">collie; cocker spaniel; pug; poodle;</div>
<div class="my-data">poodle; german shepherd;</div>
<div id="container" ></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the javascript

```
var dataArray = [];

$("body").append("<ul id='new-list'></ul>");

var newList = $("#new-list");

$(".my-data").each(function(){
var tempArray = $(this).text().split(";");

for(var temp in tempArray){

    var item = tempArray[temp];

    if( item !='' && $.inArray(item, dataArray) == -1) {
        dataArray.push(item);
        newList.append("<li>"+item +"</li>");
    }

}

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yycYb/21/

Comment: This is also a nice approach, but didn't accomplish the secondary goal of sorting the data alphabetically.